# How do I change column of a 2d list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a program that needs to change all of a certain column's values to 1. Originally I thought that `n[:][0] = 1` would have been sufficient, but it doesn't work.

```
n = [[0] * 3 for _ in range(3)]
print(n) #output: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

[...] #change all of column 0 of 2d list "n" to 1
print(n) #output: [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: So write the loop in one line?

Comment: `for x in n: x[0] = 1`

Comment: @kalkr That loop is **the** pythonic way to do it.

Comment: `[[1 if c == 0 else j for c,j in enumerate(k)] for k in n]`

Comment: Or initialize with `n = [[0] * 3] * 3` and then do `n[0][0] = 1`. It's a feature! :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an overboard one liner:

```
result = list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: y[1] + 1 if y[0] == 0 else y[1], enumerate(x))), n))

print(result)
# [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Or something even easier to read, as suggested in the comments:

```
[[1 if c == 0 else j for c,j in enumerate(k)] for k in n]
```

In comparison to a simple loop where you update the element in place:

```
for x in n:
    x[0] = 1

print(n)
# [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

**Note:** The first way using `lambda(map(...))` is just a joke, by no means use it. It's main purpose was to just show the contrast between trying to get a one liner, and just using a simple loop to do the job.

**EDIT:**

@Stefan Pochmann in the comments recommended this one-liner solution:

```
[[1] + k[1:] for k in n]
```

Which creates a new structure, instead of modifying the elements in place.

Comment: `[[1] + k[1:] for k in n]`

Comment: Or in general, for column j: `[k[:j] + [1] + k[j+1:] for k in n]`

Comment: But the loop still wins, unless they need a new structure instead of modifying the old one.

Answer (score 0):

big hammer approach - if you want array addressing, import numpy

```
import numpy as np

n = [[0] * 3 for _ in range(3)] 

nary = np.array(n)  # or: np.zeros((3,3))

nary[:, 0] = 1

nary.tolist()
Out[120]: [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```